# Sum by category in Piechart (Dc.js & Crossfilter)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I try to use `dc.js` and `Crossfilter` but I have some problem by adding values having the same category.

I explain : I have for the demo 3 columns (Project, Amount, Action).
Then I create amount categories with this code:

```
   var amount = d.amount;
        if (amount<=10) {
            return '< 10';
        } else if (amount >10 && amount < 50) {
            return '<50';
        } else if (amount >= 50 && amount <= 80) {
            return '< 80';
        } else {
            return '> 80';
        }
```

All I want is : if it's the same project, add all the amount and create these categories.

So in `< 10` category there is only *Redaction*. In the `>10 and <50` category there'll be *design* and *website hosting*... And if `>50` there'll be *Website Design*.

Here is the Jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nicart/179n4bfg/6/

Thank you for your help, I'm totally lost.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to dynamically calculate this category? For example, if the "Design" project had a "stuff" action with a value of 5, and a filter were applied to only show "stuff", then "Design" would fall into the "<10" category? Or do you want each project categorized according to it's overall value no matter what filters are applied?

If the former, you're going to have to create a group wrapper to create a "fake" group and re-aggregate a standard group on your Project dimension into your categorical values at run-time. See here, where it talks about creating a "fake group": https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ

If the latter, then you should do this as a pre-calculation step and add a category dimension to your underlying data for each record.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ethan.
I'm going to search that way.
In fact I want each project enter in the good category. So if "Design" has only an action of 5, it must go in the category "<10".

Comment: Yup, then you need to go the "fake group" route, as far as I can see. Good luck! If you have trouble, happy to look again.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out [Pie Chart](http://jsfiddle.net/iSudeep/0s3jrhtp/).
`.label` method used.

Hope this answers your question to some extent. You may modify if it helps.
Let me know :-)

Comment: Thanks Greenhorn, but I had a few time to make the project so I used `Consolidate`in `Excel` ^^... shame on me ! Good to know for the next time :)